# naive bayes classifier dynamic training

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes, online-machine-learning

Is it possible (and how if it is) to dynamically train sklearn MultinomialNB Classifier?
I would like to train(update) my spam classifier every time I feed an email in it.

I want this (does not work):

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
clf = MultinomialNB()
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    clf.fit([x_train[i]], [y_train[i]])
preds = clf.predict(x_test)
```

to have similar result as this (works OK):

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-learn supports incremental learning for multiple algorithms, including MultinomialNB. Check the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning)

You'll need to use the method [`partial_fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit) instead of `fit()`, so your example code would look like:

```py
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
clf = MultinomialNB()
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    if i == 0:
        clf.partial_fit([x_train[i]], [y_train[I]], classes=numpy.unique(y_train))
    else:
        clf.partial_fit([x_train[i]], [y_train[I]])
preds = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Edit: added the `classes` argument to `partial_fit`, as suggested by @BobWazowski

Comment: Tried and it worked! Thanks!
The only thing partial_fit requires classes to be passed at the first call. As far as I understand, I should pass `classes=numpy.unique(y_train)`
PS: could you update your answer for the future reference?